# Antlr4 Adjacent Token Precedence

Tags: antlr4

I'm running into a problem while building a complex grammar. A pet grammar to illustrate it is below:

```
grammar test;

start: (r1 | r2 | .)*
r1: A B
r2: B C

// A B C are tokens
```

When the following input occurs:

```
ABC
```

The parse tree looks like this:

```
start
|   \
r1   C
| \
A  B
```

But what I actually want is for it to look like this:

```
start
|   \
A   r2
    | \
    B  C
```

I've tried reordering the rules & adding `<assoc=right>`, but nothing seems to work except removing rule `r1`, which is incorrect because I expect `AB` and `BC` to be valid inputs. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

It seems the above problem description oversimplifies the actual issue, so I'll give more details:

```
r3: rA r4          // prefers rA(classB classC) over (rA classB)classC
r4: classB? classC // also used elsewhere other than r3

rA: // rules to build A subtree, ends with classB? in 'some' cases
classB: B1 | B2 | ... | Bm
classC: C1 | C2 | ... | Cn
```

I've found that the following 'kind of' works:

```
r3: rA Bx classC | ...
```

But the following doesn't:

```
r3: <assoc=right> rA r4 | ... // still builds (rA classB)classC
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can build the tree correctly while being able to utilize `r4` and its associated code (and avoid having to put another m lines for all instances of `B`)?

PS. `rA` is expensive, so expanding `B` tokens in `r3` like above throws performance to the dogs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "'kind of' works"?  What's not quite right about that?

Comment: @MikeCargal The results are correct, but `rA` is expensive, so running through the alternatives is giving huge performance penalties. Checking for possible `BC` constructs beforehand as given in your current answer is much faster in my case.

Comment: Would reordering the start rule be acceptable? If you move the . match to the first alt, then the result would be what you expect in the pet grammar (not sure if that's the case also for the real grammar). Looks like: `start: (. | r1 | r2)*;`

Comment: @MikeLischke Doesn't putting `.` first just matches everything with the any token rule?

Comment: You are right. That was quick shot which turned out to be stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you'll find that you're really fighting the way a recursive descent parser works.

When the parser tries to match `rA` it will try to match as many input tokens as possible, and is not remotely aware of the parents subsequent rule (i.e. the current rule's "next sibling").  (`assoc = right` isn't going to make the rule look up to it's parent and next sibling, it's designed for building the correct parse trees for things like exponentiation.)

As such, you'd need to use something like a semantic predicate to "block" the wrong alternative from matching, by looking far enough ahead to determine whether it should actually match `r4` (for example).

For your example, the following grammar parses the input "AB!C2" as

[image]

```
grammar test
    ;
start: r3 EOF;
r3
    : rA r4 // prefers rA(classB classC) over (rA classB)classC
    ;
r4
    : classB? classC // also used elsewhere other than r3
    ;
rA // rules to build A subtree, ends with classB? in 'some' cases
    : A C1
    | A
    | {!( //
        _input.get(_input.index()).getType() == C1 || //
         _input.get(_input.index()).getType() == C2) //
      }? A classB?
    ;
classB: B1 | B2;
classC: C1 | C2;

A:     'A';
B1:    'B1';
B2:    'B2';
C1:    'C1';
C2:    'C2';
WS:    [ \n\r] -> skip;
OTHER: .;
```

However, that's making an assumption that You can determine an `r4` rule match by just looking ahead at the second token that rule would possibly examine.  I would suspect that this is completely untenable from a maintenance and understanding standpoint.

You could *slightly* improve maintainability by including functions using the `@parser::members` ability.  This allows you to have more complex logic for your predicate, while not littering the actual grammar too badly.

```
grammar test
    ;
@parser::members {
    private int[] laValues = new int[] { C1, C2 };

        private boolean r4Follows() {
            int la = _input.get(_input.index()).getType();
            for (int i = 0; i < laValues.length; i++) {
                if (la == laValues[i])
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}
start: r3 EOF;
r3
    : rA r4 // prefers rA(classB classC) over (rA classB)classC
    ;
r4
    : classB? classC // also used elsewhere other than r3
    ;
rA // rules to build A subtree, ends with classB? in 'some' cases
    : A C1
    | A
    | A classB {!r4Follows()}?
    ;
classB: B1 | B2;
classC: C1 | C2;

A:     'A';
B1:    'B1';
B2:    'B2';
C1:    'C1';
C2:    'C2';
WS:    [ \n\r] -> skip;
OTHER: .;
```

However, this is still likely to be a mess to maintain.  I think the bottom line is that what you're trying to do, creates an ambiguity as to which rule `classB` belongs to.

A recursive descent parser, doesn't really see an ambiguity, it just matches the rule it's working on at that time (`rA`) the best it can and that includes pulling in the `classB` match.  You'll have to introduce a semantic predicate to prevent that, and that's going to be, pretty much, unmanageable.

---

Addendum:

Against all that is holy in the ANTLR realm, I did work out a way to use the actual `r4()` rule to test for the match of a rule at the current position of the token stream.  I HIGHLY recommend you file this under "stupid ANTLR tricks".

Since this actually attempts the parse of `r4`, depending on the complexity involved, it could substantially impact performance.

Also, I can make no guarantee that this doesn't still leave some state violated, though it worked on simple examples.

NOTE: The location of the semantic predicate is important as the current index of the token stream is advancing as you progress through the rule.

```
grammar test
    ;
@parser::header {import java.util.function.Supplier;}
@parser::members {
    private BailErrorStrategy bailStrategy = new BailErrorStrategy();
    private boolean ruleMatches(Supplier<ParserRuleContext> rule) {
        boolean result = false;

        // save state
        int idx = _input.index();
        int savedState = this.getState();
        List<ParseTree> savedChildren = _ctx.children;
        _ctx.children = new ArrayList<>();
        ANTLRErrorStrategy savedErrStrategy = this.getErrorHandler();
        this.setErrorHandler(bailStrategy);
        try {
            ParserRuleContext attempt = rule.get();
            result = true;
        } catch (ParseCancellationException pce) {
            result = false;
        } finally {
            // restore state
            this.setErrorHandler(savedErrStrategy);
            _ctx.children = savedChildren;
            this.setState(savedState);
            _input.seek(idx);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
start: r3 EOF;
r3
    : rA r4? // prefers rA(classB classC) over (rA classB)classC
    ;
r4
    : classB? classC // also used elsewhere other than r3
    ;
rA // rules to build A subtree, ends with classB? in 'some' cases
    : A {!ruleMatches(this::r4)}? classB?
    | A D
    ;
classB: B1 | B2;
classC: C1 | C2;

A:     'A';
B1:    'B1';
B2:    'B2';
C1:    'C1';
C2:    'C2';
D:     'D';
WS:    [ \n\r] -> skip;
OTHER: .;
```

input "AB1C1" [image: "AB1C1" parse tree]

input "ADC1" [image: "ADC1" parse tree]

input "AC1" [image: "AC1" parse tree]

input "AB1" [image: "AB1" parse tree]

(I believe it is now required that I go sacrifice an innocent kitten to the ANTLR gods to save my soul for posting that)

Comment: I need to do different things for `AB` and `BC`, so I'd prefer the rules `r1` and `r2` stay intact instead of having to do a manual walk with a generic rule. Is this possible?

Comment: It may be possible to have the semantic predicate attempt the parse rule `r4` for example.  I'm working on putting code together to see if I can get this to work, but may or may not have time to work through it today.  I"ll update the reply if I work this out.

Comment: Your hack is impressive! It fails on `AB1` though, somehow `r4()` parses successfully even when `C` is missing. Or maybe I ported your answer wrong. Could you verify? This definitely seems to be on the right track.

Comment: On looking ahead for semantic predicates: `rA` is dynamic, so I can't always tell how much more tokens ahead I need to look. It might even encompass multiple `BC` substrings within (independent of `r4`), so a forward search for simple patterns won't work either.

Comment: I've revised the "hack" to handle the "AB1" case.  That was ANTRL error recovery at work. I ran into it early on and forgot to test for it when I was cleaning up the hack.  I've also generalized the approach so that the predicate can test for an rule (passed in as a parameter).  **STILL NOT RECOMMENDED** (but, a proof of concept that it can be done, so I can't say "you can't do that")

Comment: With the rule matching, you would not need to know how many tokens to look ahead.  While token lookahead was simple and relatively efficient, I knew it was brittle, hence the hack to attempt the rule parse.  I hope that the take-away from the answer is that, this just isn't how recursive descent parsers are intended to work.  The first 2 paragraphs are really "the answer"

Comment: I experimented a bit and found a way to do constant token lookaheads (hopefully without breaking anything) similar to your second snippet. Works much faster than forced parsing, so I'll take it and write off the maintenance cost. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that you tell the parser to produce the parse tree you don't want. If you don't want it then don't specify the grammar that is supposed to produce it.

Similar to what Mike Cargal came up with I think the real solution is to more explicitly specify what you want to see at the end. Here's something that works pretty well (using your initial problem description and MikeC's test input):

```
parser grammar testparser;

options {
    tokenVocab = testlexer;
}

start: (A r2 | r1 | .)*? EOF;
r1: A B;
r2: B C;
```

```
lexer grammar testlexer;

A: 'A';
B: 'B';
C: 'C';

WHITE_SPACE: [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> skip ;
OTHER: .;
```

With the input `AB!C2` I get this parse three:

[image]

Leaving out `C` this changes to:

[image]

The main change is that you specialise the rule to make `BC` match in their own sub parse tree, by adding `A` for the r2 alt and put that first.

### Note

Moving that single `A` down to the r2 rule will break this, because then you tell the parser to create a sub tree with `ABC` in it (what you don't want).

Comment: Nice.  I took a wrong turn early on and got hung up on the `classB` being optional at the end of one rule and beginning of the next.  I missed moving up a level looking at the problem.

Comment: I'm interpreting this solution as saying I should cherry-pick out the offending patterns in subtree `A` and letting them have higher precedence at a high-level rule. This is impractical in my case, since the `A` subtree is _really_ complex and I can't be sure I expanded all possibilities correctly, let alone making a mess of everything both grammatically and logically.

Comment: Then maybe it would be better to accept the parse tree in its first form instead and modify your visitors/listeners to account for that. It's much easier to change how you treat the tree than trying to bring it in a form that you want.

Comment: That depends on how hard it is to implement logic for verifying the existence of such exceptions and queuing of rule actions, against changing the tree. I know the former is hard in my case; the answers here are helping me evaluate the latter.